# Why the public static void main() not working?

Tags: java

My homework tells me to do this....

*a. Create a class named Purchase. Each Purchase contains an invoice number,
amount of sale, and amount of sales tax. Include set methods for the invoice
number and sale amount. Within the set() method for the sale amount, calculate
the sales tax as 5% of the sale amount. Also include a display method that displays
a purchase’s details. Save the file as Purchase.java.*

*b. Create an application that declares a Purchase object and prompts the user
for purchase details. When you prompt for an invoice number, do not let the
user proceed until a number between 1,000 and 8,000 has been entered.
When you prompt for a sale amount, do not proceed until the user has entered
a nonnegative value. After a valid Purchase object has been created, display
the object’s invoice number, sale amount, and sales tax. Save the file as
CreatePurchase.java.*

This is what I have so far......

```
import java.util.*;
public class Purchase{
          public double invoiceNumber;
          public double saleAmount;
          public double salesTax;

          public void setInvoice(double number){
                    this.invoiceNumber = number;
}
          public void saleAmount(double sale){
                    this.salesTax = sale*.05;
                    this.saleAmount = sale;
}
          public void displayPurchase(){
                    System.out.print("Invoice Number " + invoiceNumber + " Sale Amount " + saleAmount + " Sales Tax " + salesTax);
}
}
```

```
import java.util.*;
public class CreatePurchase extends Purchase{

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          double inputSale = input.nextDouble();
          double inputNumber = input.nextDouble();

      public void valueChecker(){

                if(1000 >= inputSale && inputSale <= 8000){
                saleAmount(inputSale);
                invoiceChecker();
          }

          else if(inputSale <= 0){

                System.out.print(" Not a valid invoice ");
                }
      }

      public void invoiceChecker(){

          setInvoice(inputNumber);
          displayPurchase();

      }
      public static void main(String[] args){
      }
}
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You have an empty `main` method and you expect something to happen in your program? Its like giving you no assignments to do and then being surprised that you haven't done any assignment.

Comment: I think your core mistake is `CreatePurchase extends Purchase` - there is no reason the purchase creator should `extend` the `Purchase` class.

Answer (score 9):

because you haven't called anything in `main` method. Your `main` method is empty.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     // you need to call other methods from here
     CreatePurchase purchaseObject = new CreatePurchase();
     purchaseObject.valueChecker();// or whatever method you want to call depending upon your logic. 
  }
```

Comment: one of best answers in SO ever... xDDDDDD

Comment: @JordiCastilla I use sarcasm a lot, but I'm not sure I've understood it this time :D :D

Comment: it's simple, effective and IMHO super funny answer... not sarcasm for the answer itself, but the powerful meaning of it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreatePurchase extends Purchase {
    public void invoiceChecker(double inputnumber, CreatePurchase cp) {
        cp.setInvoice(inputnumber);
        cp.displayPurchase();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double inputSale = input.nextDouble();
        double inputNumber = input.nextDouble();
        CreatePurchase cp = new CreatePurchase();
        System.out.println(inputSale + "  " + inputNumber);
        if (inputSale >= 1000.0 && inputSale <= 8000.0) {
            cp.saleAmount(inputSale);
            cp.invoiceChecker(inputNumber, cp);
        } else if (inputSale <= 0.0) {
            System.out.print(" Not a valid invoice ");
        }
    }
}
```

TestInput and Output;

```
1500.2
3.0
1500.2  3.0
Invoice Number 3.0 Sale Amount 1500.2 Sales Tax 75.01
```

Comment: you can merge both answers.

Comment: all of these have given me multiple errors......can you guys please not make me feel stupid, i know this is probably stupid but can you just show me?

Comment: It would be nice if you could merge both of your answers Mohan.

Comment: Thanks Prasad.. Jose check the modified code above with the sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

1)Do you get any compile time error?
Method invocation of java search for main method to execute but in the current 
main method, It does not have anything to execute or NIL calls

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      }
```

So nothing will be executed.Call the methods from the main method with the required inputs so that main methods will execute with the call invocation.